# How to get rid of default overhang in Scenegraph Developer extensions

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

Where in Scene graph Developer Extensions do I set the Overhang?

When I add it to the Mainscene, or either the Grid handler.  It overlaps the default instead of replacing it.  I cannot find in SGDEX were the default overhang settings are.  No documentation on it anywhere.

Where in the SGDEX script do you set the overhang?

When I add it to the Mainscene, or either the Grid handler.  It overlaps the default instead of replacing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The default overhang is located in the following location and the following file.

pkg:/components/SGDEX/Views/SGDEXComponent/SGDEXComponent.xml

This can be closed.